# Import texture on downloaded object

Tags: texturing

So i have downloaded an object, when i open it on blender, it shows gray object (no texture). There is a file called "character texture.psd", how do i apply the .psd file on my object? I'm new on blender, glad you'll help.

Comment: As Mr Zak said, .psd is a proprietary Adobe **project filetype**, which is not supported by Blender. You will have to import the file into an application compatible with Photoshop document files and export to a supported **raster format** (jpg, png, tiff etc)

Comment: @veryRandomMe PSD *is* supported, but there are limitations, see: https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2013-October/059753.html

Comment: @RayMairlot good to know